# how to convert integer array to separated numbers in php

Tags: php, arrays

What would be the most simple way to convert an Array Integer to separate numbers?

Example:

```
array(2,4,6)
```

should result in:

`num1=2,num2=4,num3=6`

Comment: So have you tried anything???

Comment: use a loop like for() to get your numbers

Comment: Why can't you use the array as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tried "list"?

```
list($num1, $num2, $num3) = $myArray;
```

See http://php.net/list for more details.

Answer (score -1):

If you have associative array than You can use php built in function `extract()`.

Example:

```
$abc = array('var1'=>2, 'var2'=>4, 'var3'=>6);
extract($abc);
echo $var1.$var2.$var3; //Outputs 246
```